How can i get receive messages in a DMChannel by an user?
I need to know how to get any messages sends by an user.
So, i got a new DMChannel in a button interaction:
class ticketView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label='GFX', style=discord.ButtonStyle.gray)
    async def gfx_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        guild = await aclient.fetch_guild(12xxxxxxxxxxx63)
        user = interaction.user
        
        overwrite = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False), 
        }

        for role_id in suporte:
            roles = guild.get_role(role_id)
            overwrite[roles] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)  

        try:
            category = await guild.fetch_channel(categoria)
            ticket = await category.create_text_channel(
                name=f'gfx_{user.display_name}',
                overwrites=overwrite
            )

            embed=discord.Embed(title="Request", 
                                description="Is there a new request!",
                                color=0xE67E22)    
            
            await ticket.send(content=f':bell: | New order from {user.mention}!',        embed=embed)
            try:
                dm = await user.create_dm()
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="Support",
                    description="Your ticket has been created!",
                    color=0xE67E22,
                    timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
                )

                embed.set_footer(text="- SupplyHorizon",
                                icon_url=guild.icon.url)
                
                await dm.send(embed=embed)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Error: {e}')

I want know how to get any messages send by the user in the "dm" channel (dm = await user.create_dm()) and print the content.

I'm not here to do your job. I'm just going to give you a guide on how you can do this using the Client.wait_for() method.
import discord
import asyncio


def analyze_message(msg: discord.Message) -> bool:
    if msg.channel.id == DM_CHANNEL_ID:
        #  here you decide what to do with the messages
        print(msg.content)
        #  the check must be a synchronous function
        #  to use a coroutine here, you need to create a task
        asyncio.create_task(ticket.send(msg.content))
    # the wait_for method will run until this check returns True
    # here I'll just return False
    # but remember to add a stop condition
    return False


await interaction.client.wait_for('message', check=analyze_message)

